# Flows on a compact smooth manifold.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, gradient-flows

**Statement:** Let $f$ be a real-valued smooth function on a compact n-manifold $M$.Suppose it have finitely many critical points $\left\{p_1,...,p_k\right\}$ with associated critical values $\left\{c_1,...,c_k\right\}$.Choose a Riemannian metric $g$
  on $M$
 , let $X$
  be the vector field $X=\text{grad}f/|\text{grad}f|_{g}^{2}$
  on $M\backslash\{p_{1},...,p_{k}\}$
 , and let $\theta$
  denote the flow of $X$
 . Show that $f(\theta_{t}(p))=f(p)+t$
  whenever $\theta_{t}(p)$
  is defined.

**Question:** Can someone give me some hints as to how to start this problem. Thanks.

Comment: How is that vector field defined on $p_1, \cdots p_k$?

Comment: Sorry it should have been that the vector field is defined on $M\backslash\{p_1,...,p_k\}$

Comment: Notice your vector field is $f$-related to $d/dt$ (see my question here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205489/flows-of-f-related-vector-fields )

Comment: Did you try to use chain rule to differentiate $f(\theta_t(p))$ with respect to $t$?

Comment: No I haven't tried differentiating. I'll see and get back to you if I need any help.

Comment: Alright so I think I figured it out using John and Pedro's hint. Thanks a lot.